# Change rendering mode of WinForm WebBrowser component

Tags: c#, winforms, registry, webbrowser-control

Is there a way to change the rendering mode of WebBrowser component (from IE7 to IE11) without registry change? Or at least without administrator rights within the application? Some kind of reflection trick?

We are running on newest .net framework.

If there is not, any suggestion for free 3rd party browser components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my question.
What helped us to solve this was to add following snippet into the web.config. No need to change registry, or having administration rights.

```
<httpProtocol>
   <customHeaders>
      <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=EmulateIE11" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```